# How to create a scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext

Tags: scala, concurrency, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

How to create a `scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext` ?

The documentation generally gives an overall summary and mentions the "default" implementation of `scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.global`.

Still, sometimes you have to create your personal E.C., without using `akka` and other such tools.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If you want a **fork-join** pool:

```
ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(
  new java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool(initialParallelism: Int)
)
```

If you want a **fixed size** thread pool:

```
ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(limit: Int))
```

Comment: @DavidWeber, can you update the link to point to new URL?

See https://blog.jessitron.com/2014/01/29/choosing-an-executorservice/ for an explanation about the different executors that are available. (Sadly the link in the useful comment above has changed.)

Comment: See https://blog.jessitron.com/2014/01/29/choosing-an-executorservice/ for an explanation about the different executors that are available.

Answer (score 4):

I came across this recently and it's worth noting that:

```
type ForkJoinPool in package forkjoin is deprecated (since 2.12.0): use java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool directly, instead of this alias
```

The remedy for me was to replace the import of

```
import scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool
```

with

```
import java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool
```

Everything then compiled as per the advice from VasyaNoviKov

Comment: I think this should've been a comment, not a separate answer? Anywyay, thanks for the ambiguity tip, I've edited my answer to make it more clear.